# HQL 'parsename' equivalent

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql

I've discovered PARSENAME function as a good choice to order IP address stored in Database. [Here](http://drsql.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!80677FB08B3162E4!959.entry) there is an example.
My issue is I'm using Hibernate with named queries in a xml mapping file and I am trying to avoid the use of

```
session.createSQLQuery(..)
```

function.
I'm wondering if exists any PARSENAME equivalent function for HQL queries. I'm searching for it and cannot find anything.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find anything related.
Finally I executed the following ORDER BY clause to order the IP addresses in numeric way (I found the solution [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)):

```
order by cast(substring(host.ip, 1, locate('.', host.ip) - 1) as integer),
                 cast(substring(host.ip, locate('.', host.ip) + 1, locate('.', host.ip, locate('.', host.ip) + 1) - locate('.', host.ip) - 1) as integer),
                 cast(substring(host.ip, locate('.', host.ip, locate('.', host.ip) + 1) + 1, locate('.', host.ip, locate('.', host.ip, locate('.', host.ip) + 1) + 1) - locate('.', host.ip, locate('.', host.ip) +  1) - 1) as integer),
                 cast(substring(host.ip, locate('.', host.ip, locate('.', host.ip, locate('.', host.ip) + 1) + 1) + 1, 3) as integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your dialect and use `RegisterFunction()` to make PARSENAME available to HQL queries. `RegisterFunction` is not very well documented but there are [plenty of examples on the web](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%2Bnhibernate+dialect+RegisterFunction). I'm not sure you can use it to *order* results though.